# Access data JSON in react native

Tags: json, react-native

Hi i want to access the property `videoId'`of my json array in react-native in order to display a video but I'm getting the error **Cannot read property 'videoId' of undefined.** Here is my response of `dataVideos[0]` :

[image]

And I'm trying to get :

```
youtubeDisplay(){
    <View style = {{height:200}}>
    <YouTube
    ref={this._youTubeRef}
    apiKey= {this.apiKey}

    videoId= {this.state.dataVideos[0].contentDetails.videoId}

    play={this.state.isPlaying}
    loop={this.state.isLooping}
    fullscreen={this.state.fullscreen}
    controls={1}
    style={[
      { height: PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(this.state.playerWidth / (16 / 9)) },
      styles.player,
    ]}
    onError={e => {
      this.setState({ error: e.error });
    }}
    onReady={e => {
      this.setState({ isReady: true });
    }}
    onChangeState={e => {
      this.setState({ status: e.state });
    }}
    onChangeQuality={e => {
      this.setState({ quality: e.quality });
    }}
    onChangeFullscreen={e => {
      this.setState({ fullscreen: e.isFullscreen });
    }}
    onProgress={e => {
      this.setState({ currentTime: e.currentTime });
    }}
  />
  </View>
  }
```

How can I access to `videoId` ? Thanks

EDIT : Here is the code where I'm getting the response from the API.

```
 _fetchPlaylist(){
    if(this.state.selectedIndex === 0) {
      return(
      fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet,contentDetails&maxResults=${results}&playlistId=PLSlVQ0kIy6qx-f5O3J3GwIEOO5Y52z43-&key=${apiKey}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
        const videoId = []
        result.items.forEach(item => {
          videoId.push(item)
        })
        this.setState({
          dataVideos:videoId
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
      })
      )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: In my render function just after `render()` and dataVideos in declared in my constructor as a state

Answer (score 0):

is this log of this.state.dataVideos[0]? Try to use giving manual id like `lYigBSIZ6B0` if it worked then check your state maybe you miss the setstate before the run the method.

Comment: Yeah this is the log of `{this.state.dataVideos[0]}`. It returns me `undefined` on contentDetails and on videoId. But when I'm fetching it from the API I can access it. I have edited my post with the part of code where I'm getting the json response

Comment: can you log and add a picture of  => console.log(this.state.dataVideos)

Comment: Just edited it with the picture of this.state.dataVideos

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the videoId in componentWillMount()

Comment: I've tried but same result, `can't access property 'contentDetails' from undefined`